# put the variable names in x-axis instead of the value

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-analysis

my code about create Frequency distribution table and representation this to histogram and is working for me and this photo for the output [image]

my question is possible to put variables in the x-axis and delete the value(i mean change the x-axis from value to variable) i try to do but unfortunately isn't working

this my code

```
 import plotly.express as px
 import pandas as pd
 minNumber = df['age'].min()
 maxNumber =df['age'].max()
 frequency= df['age'].count().sum()
  = np.log(frequency) / np.log(2)
 import math
  = math.ceil()
 
 h = (maxNumber - minNumber) / 
 math.ceil(h)
 list1 =[]
 list2=[]
 list3=[]
 list4=[]
 list5=[]
 list6=[]
 list7=[]
 list8=[]
 list9=[]
 list10=[]
 list11=[]
 list12=[]
 list13=[]
 for x in df['age']:
   if x <= 13:
    list1.append(x)
   if 13< x <= 20:    
     list2.append(x)
   if 20<x<= 27:
     list3.append(x)
   if 27<x<= 34:
     list4.append(x)        
   if 34<x<= 41:
      list5.append(x)    
   if 41<x<= 48:
     list6.append(x)
   if 48<x<= 55:
     list7.append(x)    
   if 55<x<= 62:
     list8.append(x)        
   if 62<x<= 69:
     list9.append(x)       
   if 69<x<= 76:
     list10.append(x)
   if 76<x<= 83:
     list11.append(x)
   if 83< x<= 90:
     list12.append(x)   
   if 90<x<= 97:
     list13.append(x)  
    
 s1 = pd.Series(list1, name='list1')
 s2 = pd.Series(list2, name='list2')
 s3 = pd.Series(list3, name='list3')
 s4 = pd.Series(list4, name='list4')
 s5 = pd.Series(list5, name='list5')
 s6 = pd.Series(list6, name='list6')
 s7 = pd.Series(list7, name='list7')
 s8 = pd.Series(list8, name='list8')
 s9 = pd.Series(list9, name='list9')
s10 = pd.Series(list10, name='list10')
s11 = pd.Series(list11, name='list11')
s12 = pd.Series(list12, name='list12')
s13 = pd.Series(list13, name='list13')
ll = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13], axis=1)
fig =px.histogram(ll)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order to change the name on an axis using plotly by changing the string associated with y when you do `fig = px.histogram(11)` in order to do this, you may have to add the parameter like this `fig = px.histogram(11, y ="variable")`. If this does not work, you could try updating the axis. My example above might not work perfectly. here is the link to the plotly documentation section I looked at that has some examples that may be helpful. Let me know if you still have problems!

https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/